# Application for the trace inequality.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, trace, boundary-value-problem, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I know two theorems about the trace inequality.

Suppose that $\Omega$ is a bounded domain with smooth boundary.

One is that:
$$
\gamma_0(H^1(\Omega)) = H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\partial \Omega)
$$
where   $\ \ \ \
\gamma_0:H^1(\Omega) \rightarrow L^2(\partial \Omega) 
\quad\quad$
$
u\rightarrow u|_{\partial \Omega}
$.

The other is that:
$$
\gamma_1(H^2(\Omega)) = H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\partial \Omega)
$$
where $\ \ \ 
\gamma_1:H^2(\Omega) \rightarrow L^2(\partial \Omega)
\quad\quad\quad$
$
u\rightarrow \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}|_{\partial \Omega}.
$

So if given any $v\in H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\partial \Omega)$, I know that there exist some $\{\phi_i\}\in H^2(\Omega)$ such that
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}|_{\partial \Omega} = v
$$
and $\|\phi_i\|\leq\|v\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$.

> Question: Dose exist some $\phi\in H_0^1$ in $\{\phi_i\}$? Intuitively it's right  because I think the normal derivative won't affect the boundary value. I really hope for some reference and the answer or some motivation. Thanks a lot.